# Jmeter - Redirect doesn't happen under load

Tags: jmeter-5.0

During the distributed load test, some of the threads (of 1250 spread across 8 VMs) are having issues in following the redirection and fails at the assertions. This happens after some 30-40 mins into the test. If thread-x fails at a Y iteration, then all the following iterations are having the same issue.

The JVM size is increased to 6GB (VM has 8GB Memory). We tried to force reset the status of httpclient by setting the flag
`httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration=true`

When visiting page-x it redirects to a login page, say `page-x/login?returnUrl=%2f` with the HTTP-302 code. The Assertion to the sampler check for the text "Please submit your credentials".

The script/test works just fine perfectly for 30-40 mins and at some point there are too many errors stating the assertion failed. Inspecting more on the treeview, the page-x responds with 302 as expected, but the assertion marks that as failed.

The expectation is that jmeter follows the redirection as it did in the first 30-40 mins duration.

However the redirect doesn't happen for some reason (it could be an issue with assertion / jmeter didn't follow the redirect at all for some reason), and this error occurs only during a load test at random time.

Has anyone experienced the same before and found a solutions?